# Why doesn't Java allow me to access private method through method of the same class?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, casting

I have code that looks like this:

```
public class A<T extends A> {
    private T one() { return (T) this;}

    protected T two() { return (T) this;}

    protected void three() { two().one(); }
}
```

And IntelliJ tells me that "one() has private access in A", but hey, why can't I call the private member of the same class?

Comment: `T` is some class which extends `A` but might not be an `A`

Comment: because it is protected! that simple. its the esence of OO. thats why on object we use get methods to return a variable instead of accessing it directly

Comment: [From the horse's mouth](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html). Children of a class can't access their parent's private methods because... that's how the language was designed.

Comment: "Children of a class can't access their parent's private methods" But i try to access them in the parents class! If i'm write `class A { public void method(A obj) {` then i can access private members of class A, but passed obj can be a children of this class. So why in this case it don't works?

Comment: It's a little unrelated but note that even if this did work, you wouldn't be able to chain more than 2 in a line. For that, you should declare it as `A<T extends A<T>>`, which will allow indefinite chaining.

Comment: This is a good question. As @Peter Lawrey said, `T` extends `A` but might not be `A`- but if `T` extends `A` then an instance of `T` will have a method `one`, which can only be defined in class `A`.  I get why it'd be bad to access a member from a scope that has no guarantees about its definition, but the calling scope here has a guaranteed concrete definition- no extension of `A` could modify the behavior of `one`, could it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, why super-class method can't access protected or private methods/variables from sub-class instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899414/in-java-why-super-class-method-cant-access-protected-or-private-methods-variab)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`private` members can be accessed only within class in which they ware declared. So if you have class

```
class X{
    private int field = 1;
    private void method(){}
    void foo(X x){
        x.field = 2;
        x.method(); // this is OK, because we are accessing members from instance of X 
                    // via reference of class X (which is same class as this one)
    }

    void bar(Y y){// = lets assume that Y extends X
        y.field = 3;
        y.method(); // ERROR: we can't access `method()` 
    }
}
```

As you see we are not allowed to access private member from derived class even if we are inside class in which this member was declared.

Possible reason for this is that private members are not inherited to interface of derived class (which is kind of whole purpose of `private` visibility modifier). Because of that in such classes it is possible to redeclare these members any way author wants, for instance someone could create class like this one:

```
class Y extends X{
    private String field = "foo";
    private String method(){
        return "bar";
    }
}
```

So as you see it is possible that by calling `y.method()` you are trying to access `method` declared in `Y` class, but you don't have access to it from `X` class (due to encapsulation). And this is scenario compiler assumes ***because fields and private methods are not polymorphic***.

To avoid this confusion you will need to explicitly state that you want to invoke private member from current class X by using casting

```
void bar(Y y){
    ((X)y).method(); 
}
```

---

Same thing happens for `<T extends A>`. Since `T` can be any subclass of `A` compiler will not allow access to its private members. So you will need to cast it back to `A`

```
class A<T extends A> {
    private T one() { return (T) this;}

    protected T two() { return (T) this;}

    protected void three() { ((A)two()).one(); }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

This compiler error was introduced in Java 7 as per http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html:

> Description: In JDK 5.0 and JDK 6, javac erroneously allowed access to private members of type-variables. This is wrong, as the JLS, Java SE 7 Edition, section 4.4, states that the members of a type-variable are the members of an intersection types whose components are the type-variable bounds (intersection types are defined in section 4.9) - and intersection types do not inherit private members from their components

The type of `T` may not be `A`. It can be of type `B` that is a subclass of `A`. In this case, accessing the `private` method `one()` does not conform to the inheritance rule which says that a subclass (that is class `B`) does not inherit the `private` members of its parent class (that is class `A`).

Comment: Okey, i just checked it with usual types, without generics, and it works in same way. But i still don't understand why? We know, that we have a subtype of class A, so why we can't access the members, that are private in A, on variable of subclass? We are eventually trying to access them from A class, we don't breaking any inheritance/encapsulation rules.

Answer (score 5):

> why i can't call the private member of the same class?

Because you try to call the private method from `T` wich can be derived from `A`. If you add a cast to `A` again it will work:

```
protected void three() { ((A)two()).one(); }
```