# protected access java issue

Tags: java, protected

Why does the following code get compile error?

```
public class A
{    
   protected int _i;
   public A(int i)
   {
       _i=i;
   }
   public boolean equals(Object other)
   {
       System.out.print("A ");
       return ((other!=null) && (_i==other._i));
   }
}
```

The `Object` class is considered parent of `A`, that is, superclass and subclass. So how come The `Object` class doesn't have an access to protected variables?

Comment: Patents don't inherit from their children, it works the other way round

Comment: Object is a super Class in Java, In your case super class object can't use Class A protected data members.

Comment: @Art - all of the responses you've gotten say the same thing: parent-child visibility goes in one direction.  This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899414/in-java-why-super-class-method-cant-access-protected-or-private-methods-variab) explains why.  Q: Make sense?

Comment: `Vehicle` is the parent of `Car`, `Boat`, `Airplane`, `OxCart` and several hundred more classes.  Should `Vehicle` know about the attributes of all of its subclasses, even ones that haven't been thought of yet (i.e. `TimeMachine` and `Teleporter`)?

Answer (score 1):

It's not an issue about access modifiers at all. You'll get the same error even after you declare `int _i` as `public`.

The issue is child class is able to see all members of parent, but parent wont be able to see any member of child. That's why `other._i` is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking in the wrong direction :(

Subclass "B" of "A" would be able to see A's protected members.

Superclass "Object" cannot.

See this link:

[In Java, why super-class method can't access protected or private methods/variables from sub-class instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899414/in-java-why-super-class-method-cant-access-protected-or-private-methods-variab)